# cannot convert string to numbers in pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

**Issue**

I have an excel file in German format. It looks like this
[image]

I want to read the first column as numbers into pandas using the flowing code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tmp = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", dtype = {"col1": np.float64})
```

It gives me the error

```
ValueError: Unable to convert column col1 to type <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

The issue is in excel. If I modify the `col1` manuelly to number format, it solves the issue. See this new excel file:
[image]

**Approach**

I can first read `col1` as object into pandas, then I need to replace `,` to `.`, at the last I can change the string to float.

**However**

The approach is tedious. How can I solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: perhaps this answer might help you https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell pandas what decimal separator is being used.

What you could do though is create a function to do the conversion and pass it to read_excel as part of the converters argument.

```
def fix_decimal(num):
### convert numeric value with comma as decimal separator to float
  print(num)
  return float(num.replace(',', '.')) if num else 0
  
tmp = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", converters={0: fix_decimal} )
```